# Get schema of object

Tags: sql, json, object, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, schema

In Snowflake, you can query objects (such as those obtained from JSON) in various ways. The function [`object_keys`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/object_keys.html) returns the keys of an object, similar to `jq 'keys'`.

How do I obtain the schema of the object? I am looking for something similar to:

```
select magic_object_schema_fn(obj_column) from foo_table;
```

Which would perhaps return rows like

```
{
    "a": string,
    "b": int,
    "c": {
         "d": float
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not return a nested JSON with types (it could be modified to do that). It will return rows with inferred data types. It's possible that not all paths in a JSON will have inferred data types stored in metadata, so they'll be inferred on the fly. To do that, you can set the row sample size.

```
create or replace transient table T1(V variant);

insert into T1 select parse_json($${ 
  "accounting" : [   
                     { "firstName" : "John",  
                       "lastName"  : "Doe",
                       "age"       : 23 },

                     { "firstName" : "Mary",  
                       "lastName"  : "Smith",
                        "age"      : 32 }
                 ],                            
  "sales"      : [ 
                     { "firstName" : "Sally", 
                       "lastName"  : "Green",
                        "age"      : 27 },

                     { "firstName" : "Jim",   
                       "lastName"  : "Galley",
                       "age"       : 41 }
                 ] 
} $$);


set SAMPLE_ROWS = 100;

select  regexp_replace(PATH, '\\[.*\\]', '') as PATH ,TYPE
from
(
select   regexp_replace(PATH, '\\[.*\\]', '[]') as PATH
        ,TYPEOF(VALUE) as TYPE
from 
(select V from T1 limit $SAMPLE_ROWS)
    ,table(flatten(input => V, recursive => true)) META
)
where RIGHT(PATH, 2) <> '[]'
group by PATH, TYPE
```

Output:

| PATH | TYPE |
| --- | --- |
| accounting | ARRAY |
| accounting.age | INTEGER |
| accounting.firstName | VARCHAR |
| accounting.lastName | VARCHAR |
| sales | ARRAY |
| sales.firstName | VARCHAR |
| sales.lastName | VARCHAR |
| sales.age | INTEGER |

**Edit**: There is a somewhat convoluted way to get the schema output in the JSON structure in the example. Using this JavaScript UDF:

```
create or replace function PATH_ARRAY_TO_JSON("a" array)
returns variant
language javascript
strict immutable
as
$$

"strict"

var out = {};
for(let i=0;i<a.length;i++){
    set(out,a[i][0],a[i][1]);
}
return out;

function set(obj, path, value) {
    if(path in obj) return;
    obj = typeof obj === 'object' ? obj : {};
    var keys = Array.isArray(path) ? path : path.split('.');
    var c = obj;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
        var key = keys[i];
        if (!c[key] && !Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(c, key)){
            var nextKey = keys[i+1];
            var useArray = /^\+?(0|[1-9]\d*)$/.test(nextKey);
            c[key] = useArray ? [] : {};
        }
        c = c[key];
    }
    var f = keys[keys.length - 1];
    c[f] = value;
};
$$;
```

A modification to the SQL must send the paths in reverse order of their depths:

```
select PATH_ARRAY_TO_JSON(array_agg(array_construct(PATH, TYPE)) within group (order by regexp_count(PATH, '\\.') desc)) VARIANT_SCHEMA from
(
select  regexp_replace(PATH, '\\[.*\\]', '') as PATH ,TYPE
from
(
select   regexp_replace(PATH, '\\[.*\\]', '[]') as PATH
        ,TYPEOF(VALUE) as TYPE
from 
(select V from T1 limit 100), table(flatten(input => V, recursive => true)) META
)
where RIGHT(PATH, 2) <> '[]'
group by PATH, TYPE
)
;
```

Output:

```
{
  "accounting": {
    "age": "INTEGER",
    "firstName": "VARCHAR",
    "lastName": "VARCHAR"
  },
  "sales": {
    "age": "INTEGER",
    "firstName": "VARCHAR",
    "lastName": "VARCHAR"
  }
}
```

Comment: That is really good!